# what's the difference between the printf and vprintf function families, and when should I use one over the other?

Tags: c

I understand that the difference between the `printf`, `fprintf`, `sprintf` etc functions and the `vprintf`, `vfprintf`, `vsprintf` etc functions has to do with how they deal with the function arguments. But how specifically? Is there really any reason to use one over the other? Should I just always use `printf` as that is a more common thing to see in C, or is there a legitimate reason to pick `vprintf` instead?

Comment: I recommend adding the tags "printf" and "variadic-functions" to your question.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

`printf()` and friends are for normal use. `vprintf()` and friends are for when you want to write your own `printf()`-like function. Say you want to write a function to print errors:

```
int error(char *fmt, ...)
{
    int result;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    // what here?
    va_end(args);
    return result;
}
```

You'll notice that you can't pass `args` to `printf()`, since `printf()` takes many arguments, rather than one `va_list` argument. The `vprintf()` functions, however, *do* take a `va_list` argument instead of a variable number of arguments, so here is the completed version:

```
int error(char *fmt, ...)
{
    int result;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    fputs("Error: ", stderr);
    result = vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Of course, then you want a `warn()` function that works like `error()` but prints "Warning: " instead, so you create your _own_ `vprintf()` style function: `int verror(char *prefix, char *fmt, va_list args);` and have `error()` call that with "Error: " and `warn()` call it with "Warning: " but it's all semantics.

Comment: time to learn about variadic functions! This answer cleared things up, thank you.

Comment: Note: the 'v' stands for "variadic". Knowing that is useful to help me remember what the `vprintf` functions even are, since reminding myself what the 'v' stands for also reminds me what these functions are for. More on "variadic" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function.

Answer (score 17):

You never want to use `vprintf()` directly, but it's incredibly handy when you need to e.g. wrap `printf()`. For these cases, you will define the top-level function with variable arguments (...). Then you'll collect those into a `va_list`, do your processing, and finally call `vprintf()` on the `va_list` to get the printout happening.

Answer (score 0):

The main difficulty with variadic arguments is not that there is a variable number of arguments but that there is no name associated with each argument. The va_start, va_arg macros parse the arguments in memory (in most C compilers they are on the stack) using the type information contained in the format string cf. Kernighan and Ritchie, second edition, section 7.3.

Answer (score 0):

This example shows the elegance of Python. Since C/C++ cannot reconcile the difference between `int error(char *fmt, ...)` and `int error(char *fmt, va_list ap)`, thus, for every function `*printf`, it has to create two versions, i.e., one taking in `...`, the other taking in `va_list`, this essentially doubles the total number of functions. In Python, you can use `*list()` or `**dict()` to pass in a `va_list` as `...`.

Hopefully, future C/C++ can support this kind of argument processing scheme.