# Immitating printf

Tags: c, printf

What's wrong with the follwing code? How can we make the function print() to work as printf?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdarg.h>

void print(char *format,...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args,format);
    printf(format,args);
}

int main() {
   print("%d %s",5,"le");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [what's the difference between the printf and vprintf function families, and when should I use one over the other?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485805/whats-the-difference-between-the-printf-and-vprintf-function-families-and-when)

Comment: possible duplicate of [call printf using va_list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977326/call-printf-using-va-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need vprintf there. Take a look this question, it has a similiar problem: [what's the difference between the printf and vprintf function families, and when should I use one over the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485805/whats-the-difference-between-the-printf-and-vprintf-function-families-and-when)

Answer (score 7):

If you need to pass varargs, then use [`vprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf) instead.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to look at [vprintf](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/vfprintf/).  That function (and the related ones) allow you to pass along a variable argument list, and they handle the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is a `va_end()` call missing which is mandatory if using `va_start()`.

And you cannot use `printf()` if you want to use a `va_list` as argument. Take a look at 
[`vprintf()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/vprintf/).

example:

```
void print(char *format,...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args,format);
    vprintf(format,args);
    va_end(args);
}
```