# Passing float as argument screws up value

Tags: c, floating-point, unions

In my `main` function, I use the following code

```
float f = 32.0;
func("test string %f", f);
```

`func` (these are all example names) is declared as following

```
void func(const char *str, ...);
```

In my implementation of this function, I use a union called `all_types` to obtain the value of the arguments that are passed

```
union all_types
{
    void *v;
    CLObject *obj;
    char *s;
    long l;
    char c;
    float f;
    int i;
    double d;
};
```

and then give a value to that union like this

```
union all_types *o = calloc(1, sizeof(union all_types));
while ((o->v = va_arg(list, void *)) != NULL)
```

Now, when I know the argument is a float, the value for it will be very strange (I set a breakpoint to figure it out). The `i` and `l` values on the union will  be 32, as they should. However, the `f` value is some weird number like `0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000013592595`. Does anyone know why I am getting this behavior? This function works for every other type of object I have tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `va_arg` macro's second argument is the actual type of the actual argument. No conversion takes place as a result of the `va_arg` invocation. If you don't know the actual type of the actual argument, you're out of luck because there is no way to find out.

Note that default argument conversions do take place in the call itself, so it is impossible to receive a `float`, `char` or `unsigned short`. (The `float` will be converted to `double` and the other two to `int` or `unsigned int`, depending.)

This is why `printf` formats make you specify the type of the argument, except for `float`.

Comment: What I am basically doing in this function is trying to implement a sort of printf, and as with printf, I use format specifiers. By using a union combined with the specifiers, I have been able to get this to work with every other type. `float` is the only one I've had a problem with.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam: You might get lucky. Don't get used to it. It won't work on someone else's system, with someone else's compiler, or with the next version of your compiler.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam, so what you want is something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977326/call-printf-using-va-list

Comment: @RichardChambers I would, but I was doing this to add support for a custom type in printf.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam, what I have seen done for special types with printf() is to write your own version of printf().  Usually it is done by writing a special version of an in memory sprintf() type of clone since that provides quite a bit of flexibility.  To do it right you really should support variable args as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485805/whats-the-difference-between-the-printf-and-vprintf-function-families-and-when

Comment: @ChrisLoonam, take a look at this example for a starting place http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/ruby/ruby-67.6/ruby/sprintf.c

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), [variadic functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic) will convert *floats* to *double* and the undefined behavior comes in because *void ** is not compatible with *double* and so you can have no expectation as to the result. We can see this by going to the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `7.15.1.1` *The va_arg macro* which says:

> [...]If there is no actual next argument, or if type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undefined,[...]

The correct way to do this would be:

```
o->d = va_arg(list, double)
```

and you have the format specifier so this should be possible:

```
"test string %f"
             ^^
```